# Boost SOLR/LUCENE documents having certaint category / tags - simulate 'IF' function

Tags: lucene, solr, full-text-search

Problem: Add 2x boost on documents with category=999.
Solr vesion: 3.2

Tried to use:

- bq component `bq=category_id:999^2`

-> it is not acceptable as it generates an additive (not multiplicative) boost

- boost (that is multiplicative in sunspot 3.x) with a [subquery or a term component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Other_built-in_useful_query_parsers), like: `boost=sum({!term f=category_id}999,1)`

-> the term query does not return 1 or 0, but a lucene score that must be normalized

- IF function

-> not yet in solr 3.2, will be available on next release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2136

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the additive boost and found it failing? My experience is that that method works just fine in most cases.

If you want to, you can simplify the scoring formula as `sum_t match(t) * boost(t)` with `match(x)` in `{0,1}` then the query `foo (+foo +category:9999)` doubles the score relative to `foo`. The actual scoring formula has normalization terms etc. which will probably make exactly doubling impossible, but if you're really motivated you may be able to work it out - the formula is [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html).

You can always write your own Weight class, of course.